# How to give array[i][0] every each one of the li elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, prototype

The basic concept of my code is when I hover one of the `li` elements, the function goes comparing between `li`'s index and array's index. When those match it, array's elements are showing up on the li's element.

And my expectation is **if array includes/has any other arrays** like this form `[... 'Whale', ['Dog', 'Wolf']]`, then the `li` element shows only `0` from the inner div (`creatures[i][0]` in my case.) So the final form would be like 0-0, 1-1, 2-2[0], 3-3[0] and it goes on.

```js
function customArray() {
  var array = Object.create(Array.prototype);
      array = Array.apply(array, [null, ...arguments]);
  return (array);
}

var creatures = new customArray([
    ['Seal', 'Whale', ['Dog', 'Wolf', 'Hound'], ['Cat', 'Lion', 'Jaguar'], 'Bear'],
    ['1', '2', ['3', '30', '300'], ['4', '40', '400'], '5']
]);

  $('div ul li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var i = $(this).index() + 1;
        j = i;
    creatures.forEach((items, index) => {
      var breakPoint = Array.isArray(items), result;
      result = (breakPoint) ? true : false;
      if (i = j) {
        for(n = 0; n < creatures.length + 1; n++) {
          if(result) {
            $('nav ul li:nth-child('+ n +')').html(items[i-1][0]);
          } else {
            $('nav ul li:nth-child('+ n +')').html(creatures[i]);
            console.log('false')
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
   div {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     opacity: 0.5;
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: row;
     z-index: 1;
   }
   ul {
     display: flex;
   }
   li {
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: column;
     justify-content: center;
     list-style: none;
     color: white;
     padding: 0 20px;
   }
   nav {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
   }
   .black {
     background-color: black;
   }
   .orange {
     background-color: orange;
   }
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <ul>
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li>
    <li>menu 3</li>
    <li>menu 4</li>
    <li>menu 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<nav class="orange">
  <ul>
    <li>smenu 1</li>
    <li>smenu 2</li>
    <li>smenu 3</li>
    <li>smenu 4</li>
    <li>smenu 5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

This is the code that have an issue and it pops up the error that says `Cannot read property '0' of null at forEach.creature.`.

Any tips would be pleasure.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `customArray` function makes no sense. What is it supposed to achieve? It doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi `customArray` makes the index of array starts 1, not 0. so It goes 1, 2, 3, 4, ... and it goes on.

Comment: Oh (that's weird). But why don't you just use `var creatures = [null,  ['Seal',…], ['1',…]];` for that? If you insist on make a function, you should write `function customArray(...args) { return [null].concat(...args); }`

Comment: @Bergi I add that for less calculating at the inside of the mouseenter code block.

Comment: @Bergi lol I didn't think that way :D Thanks for advice.